# Automatic Documentation for Azure

Tags: azure

I need to get an automatic generated diagram of my infra asociated to my subscription in Microsoft Azure.
So far, I saw Azure Dockit which is fine but offers much more info than I need. I also saw http://armviz.io but I don't know to export the image to png. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is if there is any product (Software or Service) which I can use to automatically generate a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lucidchart to generate the Azure diagram.
It allows easy import and export of several kinds of files such as png.

For more details,you can refer to this [article](https://lucidchart.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207299976-Microsoft-Azure-Diagrams).

> **Microsoft Azure Diagrams**
>
> This article will teach you how to create a Microsoft Azure diagram by importing from a Visio file or starting from scratch in Lucidchart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that automatic?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm also not sure if it's automatic. Azure Shapes seems to need to pay, you can try the trial version yourself.(https://www.lucidchart.com/users/registerLevel?utm_source=Chart_HC&t4=A&tP=1&__hstc=215508872.bd4c9a6fae6cc53c0d8f58c7c049d99e.1467402096587.1468264075091.1468267227250.14&utm_campaign=Pricing_Page&t10=A&referer=https%3A%2F%2Flucidchart.zendesk.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Farticles%2F207299976-Microsoft-Azure-Diagrams&utm_medium=5_Active&__hsfp=4208821684&__hssc=215508872.22.1468267227250)